# Stuck on sockets.io hello world. Not sure how to run the app?

Tags: node.js, http, express, websocket, socket.io

Such a dumb question, sorry about that. So I've downloaded node.js/sockets.io/express.js. Trying to make a simple multiplayer game, but starting with hello world currently.

I have the following directory structure:

```
-index.html
-server.js
-package.json
-node_modules/
```

The server.js has the following code:

```
var app = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io');
/*
var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
}).listen(80);
*/

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(80);

var socket = io.listen(server);

var usersCount = 0;

socket.on('conection', function(client){
    ++usersCount;
    console.log('client connecting... client# = ' + userCount);
    client.emit('onMessageReceived',{msg:"You are client number: " + userCount});
});
```

My client code is in index.html, and its contents are:

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title> Client Code </title>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var socket = new io.Socket({'127.0.0.1',{port:80}});
        socket.connect();
        socket.on('connect', function(obj){
            console.log('client connection successful..');
        });
        socket.on('onMessageReceived', function(data){
        console.log("client has received message: " + data.msg);
        });
    });
  </script>
 </body>
```

and my package.json contains:

```
{
  "name": "hello_world",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "hello world test program",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "BSD",
  "dependencies":{
    "express":"3.0.5",
    "http": "",
    "socket.io":""
  }
}
```

Now I'm not sure how to proceed to run the app, if I am even finished. Any help on how to proceed next. I am guessing now I need to have server.js run constantly, and have multiple clients open up index.html to connect to the server.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that your not declaring your server properly. You need to create an instance of the express server which since [express 3.x](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x) looks like this

```
var io = require('socket.io')
  , express = require('express');

var app = express()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = io.listen(server);
```

You can then set your server listening to a port

```
server.listen(8080);
```

You can then [render](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render) pages

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
     res.render('index');
});
```

Comment: The results look better, I get a message body in my browser saying cannot Get/. I guess I need to declare the get functions that I've seen in tutorial before. How can I use the index.html to connect to the server? the server.js is listening to port 8080, so can I just open up the index.html and should it connect to the server?

Comment: you use the express server to render pages `app.get('/', routes.index);` you can also configure it to work with html, but as a default it uses [jade](http://jade-lang.com/). I would look into [configuring](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.configure) you express app and maybe defining a routes and a views directory to render pages from.

Answer (score 1):

First, You Don't want to really use port 80 in a hello world program it makes it harder and you have to be a root user, use port 8080 instead it is a world easier than port 80.
then to run the program open the your command line and cd in to the directory of server.js and run `node server.js`
then open localhost:8080 in the browser and on the console you should see the logs.
hope this helps

Comment: Should I have my index.html code in my ~/Sites/ directory? If I open localhost:8080 in the browser it just hangs.